# Why isn't Xilinx ISE inferring block RAM?

Tags: verilog, fpga, ram, spartan

As the title suggests, ISE is having trouble inferring block RAM from my code.

```
wire we;

reg hold = 0;
reg start = 0;

reg [12:0] addr = 0;
reg [23:0] command = 0;

reg [7:0] RAM [8191 : 0];

reg [7:0] rx_data_buffer = 0;

assign we = new_rx_data && !hold && start;

always@(posedge clk) begin

new_tx_data <= 1'b0;

if(!tx_busy && hold && !new_tx_data) begin

    new_tx_data <= 1'b1;        
    addr <= addr + 1'b1;

    tx_data_buffer <= RAM[addr];

    if(addr == 13'd8191)
        hold <= 0;

end

else if(new_rx_data && !hold) begin

    addr <= addr + 1'b1;
    command <= {command[15:0], rx_data};

    if(addr == 13'd8191)
        hold <= 1;

    if(start)
        led <= rx_data;

end

if(we)
    RAM[addr] <= rx_data;

if(command == 24'h242424) //$$$ in ASCII
    start <= 1;

end
```

I have deduced that the root of the problem is the write enable signal for my RAM. If I set it to VCC by writing

```
if(1'b1)
    RAM[addr] <= rx_data;
```

ISE infers RAM without an issue. However, this is not my intended behavior. I want the write enable signal to be

```
assign we = new_rx_data && !hold && start;
```

No matter what register I assign to "we" ISE tells me it'll be inferring distributed RAM. Has anyone dealt with this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple things probably need to be addressed.  I see you are using new_rx_data for your assign we.  I don't see it assigned in your RTL.  Is it floating? or an Input?

Addr is assigned within an IF and ELSEIF.  There is no ELSE, so in my mind that means it doesn't get assigned under some conditions.  Maybe it just retains value, but again it's not my preference to do that.

Another is that you are assigning using non-blocking assignments and potentially assigning the same variable twice(See new_tx_data), and I can't be certain how that will synthesize.  If it is unsynthesizeable, I would hope the build would crash, but it does build, you might get unexpected results.

Having said that, you need to fix these things to make sure your simulation results match the real results.  You a simulator who says odd ball assignments are okay and physical synthesis tool that resolves the issue a different way, the two results will probably be different.

So, the second thing you need to do is check your warnings.  The synthesis tool will complain about things, and it may include a noxious warning about some of the signals you are working with.  If one of the signals you are working with (check for those three signals in your assign we statement)is said to always be stuck high or always stuck low, you may have a state that means you can't write, or you can't read, or both.  This will cause RAM to not be inferred.  No point in making memory that isn't write able right?  Your always going to read zeros, so I'll just hard wire the data bus to zero for you and be done with it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. From what I remember of the Verilog standard, signals that are assigned in different places of a behavioral block will take on the value of the last assignment in the block. This is definitely supported by synthesis and simulation tools alike. Signals that are not explicitly assigned will retain their values as well. The synthesis warning was not helpful, saying I might have been using an asynchronous read. The real issue was that I was using the same address for reading and writing (not sure why). Using different registers for these values fixed the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't that infer latches and possibly lead to sim/synthesis mismatch? They way I did it above would just infer a flip-flop with an AND gate before the input.

Comment: You can safely do multiple assignments with blocking assignment like = to get the order of sequential resolution like you expect, but you shouldn't use non-blocking <= in this way as that creates a race state.  The race state could resolve in unexpected ways.  Relative to not assigning in all cases, that's more of nit-pick, but when you don't know whats going on, you might consider being more specific.

Comment: Don't know if this will help or not, but here is a link to another question about [inferred latches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009174/verilog-systemverilog-inferred-latch-in-case-statement/39009341#39009341).  There is a bit in there about using the blocking versus non-blocking assignments too.

Comment: I believe you have it backwards. Blocking assignments are much more prone to race conditions when used in clocked behavioral blocks. Take a look: http://www.vlsiencyclopedia.com/2012/08/race-condition-in-verilog.html

Comment: I agree with that statement.  But in your code above you potentially assign the same variable twice in the same clock using a non-blocking assignment.  That does create race condition.  Because you have what looks like a default assignment, it seems like a blocking architecture that got implemented in a clocked process.